# Correct way to add two elements to array and keep default index

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm having an issue with an array, I wish to **put 2 elements into my array together** in the **same element** within the array but keep the default index. Currently I have this in my array :

```
Array ( 
[0] => 2 
[1] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b99696ce2350100b000029 ) 
[2] => 1 
[3] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b998ccce2350181700002b ) 
[4] => 1 
[5] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b99a84ce2350100b00002b ) )
```

and I wish to have something like this, I think:

```
Array ( 
[0] => [number]=>2, MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b99696ce2350100b000029 ) 
[1] => [number]=>1, MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b998ccce2350181700002b )  
[2] => [number]=>1,MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b99a84ce2350100b00002b ) 
)
```

I wish to retain the **default key** as well as have two other values, I have tried a few methods but none resulted in the elements being paired together as I want:

Currently (above) I tried :

```
$array = array_merge( $array,array( $number,$doc[_id] )   );
```

I also tried :

```
 $array = array_merge( $array,array( $number=>$doc[_id] )   );
```

and:

```
array_push($array, $doc[_id], $number);
//asked here on SO earlier but this adds onto the end of an array both elements rather than adding both together into a single element
```

Can anyone advise the correct way to add two elements as a pair together whilst maintaining the default key/index value of the array.

Comment: Just put both values into an array before you push that one array as one element with `array_push()` into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append an array at the end containing the two elements

```
$array[] = array($n, $obj);
```

Or if you want to have it indexed by some name instead

```
$array[] = array('number' => $n, 'mongoid' => $obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to play with array functions:

```
array_push($array, [$number, $doc[_id]]);
```